# Why is Point.Offset() not giving a compiler error in a readonly struct?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, readonly-attribute

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the concept of a readonly struct, but I would think this code should not compile:

```
public readonly struct TwoPoints
{
    private readonly Point one;
    private readonly Point two;

    void Foo()
    {
        // compiler error:  Error CS1648  Members of readonly field 'TwoPoints.one'
        // cannot be modified (except in a constructor or a variable initializer)
        one.X = 5;

        //no compiler error! (and one is not changed)
        one.Offset(5, 5);
    }
 }
```

(I'm using C# 7.3.)
Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you post the code for Offset()?

Comment: I think we are talking about MS's `Point` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.point.offset(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way for compiler to figure out that `Offset` method mutates `Point` struct members. However, `readonly` struct field is handled differently compared to non-readonly one. Consider this (not readonly) struct:

```
public struct TwoPoints {
    private readonly Point one;
    private Point two;

    public void Foo() {
        one.Offset(5, 5); 
        Console.WriteLine(one.X); // 0
        two.Offset(5, 5);
        Console.WriteLine(two.X); // 5
    }
}
```

`one` field is readonly but `two` is not. Now, when you call a method on `readonly` struct field - a *copy* of struct is passed to that method as `this`. And if method mutates struct members - than this copy members are mutated. For this reason you don't observe any changes to `one` after method is called - it has not been changed but copy was.

`two` field is not readonly, and struct itself (not copy) is passed to `Offset` method, and so if method mutates members - you can observe them changed after method call.

So, this is allowed because it cannot break immutability contract of your `readonly struct`. All fields of `readonly struct` should be `readonly`, and methods called on readonly struct field cannot mutate it, they can only mutate a copy.

If you are interested in "official source" for this - specification (7.6.4 Member access) says that:

> If T is a struct-type and I identifies an instance field of that
>   struct-type:
>
> • If E is a value, or if the field is readonly and the reference
>   occurs outside an instance constructor of the struct in which the
>   field is declared, then the result is a value, namely the value of the
>   field I in the struct instance given by E.
>
> • Otherwise, the result is a variable, namely the field I in the
>   struct instance given by E.

`T` here is target type, and `I` is member being accessed.

First part says that if we access instance readonly field of a struct, outside of constructor, the result is *value*. In second case, where instance field is not readonly - result is *variable*.

Then section "7.5.5 Function member invocation" says (`E` here is instance expression, so for example `one` and `two` above):

> • If M is an instance function member declared in a value-type:
>
> If E is not classified as a variable, then a temporary local
>   variable of E’s type is created and the value of E is assigned to that
>   variable. E is then reclassified as a reference to that temporary
>   local variable. The temporary variable is accessible as this within M,
>   but not in any other way. Thus, only when E is a true variable is it
>   possible for the caller to observe the changes that M makes to this.

As we saw above, readonly struct field access results in a `value`, not a variable and so, `E` is not classified as variable.

Comment: That would be really weird. By just looking at the line `one.Offset(5, 5);`, I have no way of knowing if the member is being called on `one` or on some ghost copy, that is never accessible.

Comment: @ErikBongers Weird it may be, but it's correct. You *already* didn't have any way of knowing that: `Offset` could have been an extension method taking a `Point` by value, forcing a copy. Normally it doesn't matter, because self-mutating `struct` instance methods are not common, and when the method doesn't change anything, it doesn't matter whether it's called on a copy.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd rather be forced to explicitly declare members of a readonly type as readonly members. That way, the compiler can consider the other members as potentially mutating and throw a compiler error. This way I could check immutability at compile time. Because now, while trying to make my code more safe by adding `readonly` to some structs, I'm suddenly running into runtime errors because of these ghost copies. In the best case, this happens during testing!

Comment: @ErikBongers you might be interested in also reading this: http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/07/01/when-is-a-readonly-field-not-readonly/

Comment: @Evk - interesting article indeed. Thanks. I read some other articles as wel and indeed, guaranteeing readonly-ness is a nightmare for language architects. But, back to the real world now. It's weekend.

Answer (score 3):

Supporting the answer from [Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50527723/7167572), there is an article in regards the `Point's method:` [Point.Offset()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.point.offset(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)

> **Note that calling the Offset method will only have an effect if you can change the X and Y properties directly.** Because Point is a value type, if you reference a Point object by using a property or indexer, you get a copy of the object, not a reference to the object. If you attempt to change X or Y on a property or indexer reference, a compiler error occurs. Similarly, calling Offset on the property or indexer will not change the underlying object.  If you want to change the value of a Point that is referenced as a property or indexer, create a new Point, modify its fields, and then assign the Point back to the property or indexer.

---

By the definition `Point` is declared as `struct`: [Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point(v=vs.110).aspx)

Last but not least, there is [an article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/11/21/c-7-series-part-6-read-only-structs/) on Microsoft's blog, which describes that `readonly fields`, that are actually `struct`, their public properties are read-only also.

> A read-only struct is a struct whose public members are **read-only**, as well as the “this” parameter.

Comment: Well that's a weird quirk.

Comment: Weird is the word. But I'm not using a property or indexer. I'm directly calling Offset() on the Point struct. As Evk, below suggests: Offset() might be being called on some ghost copy.